# Cannot convert implicity type Syste.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymys type int>> to

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT project_id,count(project_id) as vote_count 
from Votes 
group by project_id;
```

Write it in LINQ syntax:

```
public int GetCountOfVotes()
{
    using (var db = new SafetyFundDbContext(Options))
    {

        var result = db.Votes
            .GroupBy(vote => vote.ProjectId)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                ProjectID = group.Key,
                Count = group.Count()
            });

        return result;
   }          
}
```

And C# return error :

[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: `result` is an enumerable of an anonymous type, not a single `int`, why would you expect this to work?

Comment: What I need add or change for working solution?

Comment: Well what are you trying to return here? The total number of votes for all projects? The votes per project? The votes for a single project?

Comment: How much votes got one(single) project :)

Comment: Lol, im sry, my fault but in one page i have for example 5 projects and I need votecount for every project

Comment: Solution what you write i can use for it?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. But you really need to ask your questions better, you shouldn't be having to clarify so many things in the comments.

Comment: Ok Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is an enumerable of an anonymous type, not a single int. Instead you need to return a single value. Since you need the votes for a single project, you need to tell the function which project by passing in the ID:

```
public int GetCountOfVotes(int projectId)
{
    using (var db = new SafetyFundDbContext(Options))
    {
        return db.Votes
            .Where(vote => vote.ProjectId == projectId)
            .Count();    
   }          
}
```

If you need votes for all projects, you need to change the return type to a concrete class, for example:

```
public class ProjectVotes
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int Votes { get; set; }
}
```

And your method becomes:

```
public IEnumerable<ProjectVotes> GetCountOfVotes()
{
    using (var db = new SafetyFundDbContext(Options))
    {
        return db.Votes
            .GroupBy(vote => vote.ProjectId)
            .Select(group => new ProjectVotes
            {
                ProjectID = group.Key,
                Votes = group.Count()
            })
            .ToList();
   }          
}
```